# correct way to place data in table OneToONe

Tags: mysql, sql

I am confused about the correct/most efficient way to place data in my dababase table when there is a OneToOne relationship.

For example, I have a users table.

I now wish for each user to be able to state his current country location.

i then want to be able to search the datatable for users by current location.

The way that I have done this is to create 3 separate tables. i.e

**table one - users : just contains the user information:**

```
CREATE TABLE users(
id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
firstName VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastName VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
);
```

**Table two country list: a list of countries and respective Ids for each country**

```
PHP Code:
CREATE TABLE countrylist(
country_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
country VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
INDEX country_id ( country_id, country ), 
INDEX countrylist (country, country_id ), 
UNIQUE KEY (country)

);
```

**Table 3; contains the userId and the countryId he lives in:**

```
PHP Code:
CREATE TABLE user_countrylocation(
country_id VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL, 
INDEX country_id (country_id, id ), 
INDEX user_id (id, country_id ) 
);
```

Alternatively, should I place the countryId in the users table and completely get rid of the user_countrylocation. i.e in each user column, I will place a country_id for the country he lives in.

The problem is that I have over 20 similar tables as above that give details on users; i.e languages spoken, age-group, nationality etc.

My concerns is that if I place this unique information in each users column in the user table, then what would be the most efficient way to search the database: that is why I opted for the style above.

So, I really request for some advice on the most efficient/correct way to plan the database.

Comment: This by the way is a Many to One relationship because many users can belong to one country. A more appropriate one to one relationship would be users and their cell phone numbers for example.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If someone gives you answers, be nice enough to appreciate their help by marking the answers and comments as useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to have a huge data then you should keep the same approach and use the following method to keep the one to one constraint satisfied

if you don't have a huge data then you should keep the look up tables like country and use the reference for user in a column. but then you may need to allow them nulls that is make such optional information columns nullable.

The most efficient and exactly correct way is to first delete the data from the third table "user_countrylocation" for the user to be updated. Then insert the new location for the user. don't forget to use transaction.

your table 3 should have

```
country_id MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
```

instead of

```
country_id VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
```

and also change tyhe column name from id to user_id in all tables.

if you are using a stored procedure it would be like

```
create procedure sp_UpdateUserCurrentCountry (
                 @userID MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED,
                 @CountryID MEDIUMINT UNSIGNED)

begin 
as
   delete from user_countrylocation
   where user_id = @userID

insert into user_countrylocation
           (
           country_id,
           user_id
           )
 values
           (
           @CountryID,
           @userID
           )
END
```

Comment: Hello Tauseef. Thank you so much for your prompt reply. so, in your view; if i am going to have a huge database and i want to optermise my searches, then i should really have 3 tables. This is so confusing. Everyone seems to have/give me a different opinion. I have indeed been using this approach; but when i went for a recent job interview, the interviewers felt that this was an incorrect approach: ravi also seems to suggest its an incorrect approach.

Comment: my pleasure, as I said, keep the look up tables, its a MUST. if you don't want to have a third table then keep the foreign keys but in this case start the primary key of look up table from a large value, such as 2^24 and index the foreign key column. that would be efficient and of course keeps the one to one relation.
please mark my answer helpful if it helps you. thanks

Comment: by indexing the foreign key column I mean country_id column in user table and you must choose the data type that can store your value. start value is called the "seed" for increment

Answer (score 0):

One to One relations are usually mapped via Foreign Keys linking the two tables together. A third mapping table is only required for Many to Many relationships. So, you should ideally have a Foreign Key `Country_ID` in your `Users` table.

Your `SELECT` query would then look like

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE Country_ID = (
    SELECT Country_ID FROM Countries
    WHERE Country_Name = 'USA'
);
```

Comment: Hello Ravi. thank you so much for your prompt reply. but how would this affect performance if i had twenty diffrent categories and i have to do your Select/Where clause each time.

Comment: No, for multiple countries/categories you would use the IN operator as `WHERE Country_ID IN (SELECT Country_ID FROM Countries WHERE Country_Name IN ('USA', 'UK', 'AUSTRALIA'))`. You're joining only two tables here. Although it comes down to how optimised the query is; with a mapping table, you would be joining three tables against two.